# What type of door can I install in a wide cased opening without damaging the flooring?

Tags: doors

[image: door frame]

We rent a house and we’d like to install doors in the 50” open doorframe between the master bedroom and the sunroom. We thought of French Doors, but the owner doesn’t want us to drill in the wood floors. What kind of doors could we install to accommodate that?

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Privacy? Sound blocking? Heat containment? It matters with respect to door types. Please revise to clarify your goals.

Answer (score 1):

Bi parting barn doors would not involve the floor but you need 25” clearance on either side of the opening. Also they are about 500 dollars at Home Depot
[image]

if you have good carpentry skills you could narrow the width with  a board on each side and hang 2 24” interior doors. Mortising  for hinges

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the landlord does not want you to modify the existing structure then your options are limited. The simplest would be to get by with the curtains.

If you were really handy it may be possible to build an alternate door frame that gently slides into the existing frame and then is just wedged into place using some thin taper wedges. The new door would attach to this slip in frame.

To make this work would likely require a threshold piece all along the bottom that would sit on top of the existing floor covering.

This could end up pretty ugly or looking rather nice based upon the craftsmanship applied. Two potential issues would be the reduced height in the opening and the threshold piece could be a potential trip hazard.